# How to test a selected item of a ComboBox is equal to my string?

Tags: c#

I just started learning c# a week ago. I have a little experience with objective c. So give me a hard time for asking such a beginner question.

Well, I would like the user to be able to select from the combo box. I created the combobox visually in xaml. The contents of the combo box are strings. However, when the user selects their string of choice, I would like store a value to an int so I can do calculations. The errors I have been can't convert object to string and many other conversation errors.

```
int x;
string selValue = (string)comboBox1.SelectedValue;
if ((selValue=="green")||(selValue=="blue"))
{ 
    x= 5; 
}
```

Would it be best to create a function that accepts an object and returns an int, if so please tell ?

Answer (score 0):

You should have the string green be the selectedtext and the value int 5 be the selectedvalue, that way you can drop all that code & do int x = (int)comboBox1.SelectedValue, this will give you 5.
You need to Google winform combobox databinding, you'll see that you can bind diferent properties to the text & value.

Answer (score 0):

`SelectedValue` property will return the `ComboBoxItem` as `object` and `SelectedIndex` will return `ComboBoxItem` as `integer` index.